# Android Toolbar menu actionViewClass or actionLayout cannot be right alignment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I want to have a menu icon on the toolbar, when click on this menu icon and change to checkbox icon.

Like the search icon in the toolbar. When click on search menu button, show the searchView. 
This is how the searchView is added in the menu.

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:title="@string/action_menu_search"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

So i did the same for the checkbox

```
app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
```

But the actionview is shown, it is left align to the home up button. May be it is because checkbox is wrap_content.

But i want it to be right align to the end of the parent view. 
So after checking this https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views.html

I think i can use the actionLayout. 
So i change as below:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_delete"
            android:title="delete"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_delete"
            app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/toolbar_checkbox_layout" />
```

toolbar_check_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The result is like that. It still cannot be right alignment. I want checkbox to be right side of the toolbar. Any suggestion? please. Thanks a lot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff"
tools:context="com.example.raj.jazzflurry.MainActivity">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/faqfoods_bar"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
            <include
                layout="@layout/btn_share"
                android:id="@+id/btn_share"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

btn_share.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizantal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java file (inside of on create)

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hai");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.color.colorprimary1));
```

Manifest.xml

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: I don't want to modify my toolbar as above. I just want to set action view class or action layout that can be pinned to the right.  When switch to action view, toolbar will automatically switch to home up button(back button).